# Using tar with find

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, tar

Lets say we want to find a certain files , use tar on them and delete them.
I tried using

```
touch "mycompress.bz2.tar"
find . \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.sh*" \) -exec tar ujf "mycompress.bz2.tar" {} "+" \; -exec rm {} \;
```

But executing this my terminal just get closed. How can I implement this in a correctly?

Comment: The `find(1)` manpage suggests `-exec command {} +` , without a `;`.  What happens if you remove the first `\;` ?

Answer (score 5):

There are several issues with your command.

The first one is a compressed archived cannot be updated. You would need to first create a uncompressed archive, update it and finally compress it.

The second one is the `tar` syntax is incorrect, the first `-exec` clause should use either the `+` terminator or the `\;` one, but not both.

The third one is more subtle and occur if you keep the `+` terminator, the second `-exec` clause will be executed for each file on sequence while the first one will wait for the list of files to save to fill the environment string to be launched. When this happen, all the files to be stored by the first `-exec` will have already been deleted by the second `-exec` so `tar` will fail and you'll have lost all of your files.

As there is no doubt you are using `GNU tar`, here is a simple way to achieve what you want :

```
tar --files-from <(find . \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.sh*" \)) \
    --remove-files -cjf mycompress.bz2.tar
```

GNU tar is documented to remove the files only after they have been saved:

```
$ man gtar
...
       --remove-files
              remove files after adding them to the archive
...
```

Note that the command I suggested will fail to process files with an embedded new line but that should be quite an unlikely event.

Comment: If that works, then this should, too: `find . \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.sh*" \) -print0 | xargs --null tar --remove-files -cjf mycompress.bz2.tar`.

Comment: `tar` does not implement an option `--files-from`. Thank  you for marking your answer to be related to a vendor specific implementation! But please note that either with a typical UNIX tar, that implements a portable `-I` option or with the vendor specific `gtar`, your proposal is slower than the `star` proposal.

Comment: @Michael Vehrs: Your proposal does not work, unless there are very few files to archive. In the typical case, your proposal will overwrite the archives after the files have been removed.

Comment: @schily I made it very clear my answer was requiring GNU tar. I didn't used the portable `-I` because I was already using the `--remove-files` anyway so used the more explicit `--file-from` long option.

Comment: @ jlliagre: On a typical UNIX installation, `tar` refers to the UNIX tar implementation and does not support `--files-from`. BTW: see my new note on reliability in my answer.

Comment: @schily "A very few files"? That depends on the maximum length of the command line. Granted, for very long argument lists, my solution will fail. But I'm still not going to use your shilytools. Furthermore, the OP does not explicitly mention UNIX, so I'm going to assume Linux.

Comment: @schily I perfectly know what tar refer to on a typical UNIX system. The fact is the OP is more than likely already using GNU tar, as he uses the "j" flag (bzip), not to mention GNU tar `-I` (uppercase i) flag doesn't follow the UNIX standard.

Comment: It seems that you did not visit a UNIX system since a longer time. There are of course UNIX systems that are based on the original sources but added support for `-j` aprox. 10 years ago. And yes, I know that `gtar` has some compatibility problems from not following the UNIX tar command line syntax.

Comment: @schily It looks like you are here only to self promote your software and troll other answers so I won't feed you any more.

Comment: I am not self promoting software. I mentioned an alternative tar implementation the same way as you mention an alternative implementation. You however did give an answer that is risky because it can result in accidentally removed files.

Comment: @schily I wouldn't call an alternative implementation the one used by the OP and probably about 99% of the visitors of this site. Your last statement is incorrect, GNU tar is deleting the files only if they have been successfully archived.

Comment: You did not verify that the OP did use `gtar` and this is a UNIX site, so you cannot assume that people use alternate an implementation in case this has not been verified (as in our case). Also note that `gtar` does does give transactional reliability. It does not verify whether the files have been successfully archived.

Comment: @schily I'm quite sure the OP uses Linux Mint or similar Ubuntu Gnu/Linux.

Answer (score -3):

With one of the usual `tar` implementations, this does not work.

There is a free `tar` implementation since 1982 which is called `star`.

`star` added a built-in `find` utility in 2005 based on my `libfind`.

You call `star -c -f file.out -find . \( -name "*.c" -o -name "*.sh*" \)`

The rules for the built in `find` are simple: everything to the right side of `-find` follows the command line rules for `find(1)`.

See http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/index.html

and the star man page at: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/man/man1/star.1.html

There is a separate source (see web-site), but the most recent and best version is currently part of the `schilytools`.

Please keep in mind that your wish to remove the files while archiving them is higly risky as there may be a problem with your command and then you would have removed files that you cannot use with a second try anymore. I thus recommend to first use my proposal to archive the files and later call:

`rm $(star -t -tpath < file.out)`

This will only remove files that have been successfully put into the archive.